# How to determine if a Firebase user is signed in using facebook authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase from google and I have some trouble with user authentication. After logging with facebook I obtain FirebaseUser in AuthStateListener, but how can I detect if this user is logged via facebook or differently?

UPDATE
As @Frank van Puffelen said FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderId()
should return "facebook", but in my case it returns "firebase". Now I cannot figure out what's the reason of this behavior. When I got FacebookToken I do something like this:

```
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(facebookToken.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                        }

                    }
                });
```

And afterthat before onComplete() method is called, my AuthStateListener gets user which provider id is not "facebook" as it should be. Am I doing something wrong? I followed official google [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login)

Comment: I believe that FirebaseUser.getProviderId() will return "facebook.com" but I cannot test it as my app does not use facebook. Maybe give that a try if you could?

Comment: Look at my updated question please.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In version 3.x and later a single user can be signed in with multiple providers. So there is no longer the concept of a single provider ID. In fact when you call:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderId()
```

It will always return `firebase`.

To detect if the user was signed in with Facebook, you will have to inspect the provider data:

```
for (UserInfo user: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {
  if (user.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) {
    System.out.println("User is signed in with Facebook");
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately getProviderId() in my case returns "firebase". I will update my question, would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: The code in your update does precisely what the first half of my answer explains. Did you use the loop I have in my second snippet? The first `UserInfo` will indeed have provider id `firebase` (as it is for the merged user). But the second one in my tests had `google.com` (I used the Google provider).

Comment: Of course you are right! I made simple mistake... Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how can the user be signed in with multiple providers, how does FireBase know that my google and my facebook when they are both singed into a particular FireBase backend, are the same user?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is this documented somewhere we could reference the other Provider Ids? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @kbpontius - From what I could gather: facebook - "facebook.com", email - "password", github - "github.com", google - "google.com", phone - "phone", playgames - "playgames.google.com", twitter - "twitter.com". Anonymous login seems to return "firebase", but I was unable to find any documentation confirming that.

Answer (score 5):

In my app, I use Anonymous Firebase accounts. When I connect Firebase auth with a Facebook account or Google Account I am checking like the following:

```
for (UserInfo user: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {

  if (user.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) { 
    //For linked facebook account
    Log.d("xx_xx_provider_info", "User is signed in with Facebook");

  } else if (user.getProviderId().equals("google.com")) { 
    //For linked Google account
    Log.d("xx_xx_provider_info", "User is signed in with Google");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, the following solution is working.
First, get the firebase user object if you have'nt already:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

Now use the following on the FirebaseUser object to get the sign in provider:

```
firebaseUser.getIdToken(false).getResult().getSignInProvider()
```

Sources:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/GetTokenResult.html

It will return password, google.com, facebook.com and twitter.com for email, google, facebook and twitter respectively.

Answer (score 5):

Sharing for `FirebaseAuth` targeting version `6.x.x` (Swift 5.0), year 2020:

I use `Auth.auth().currentUser?.providerData.first?.providerID`.

This will return **password** if logged in via email. And **facebook.com** if via Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

There exist information in the responding Intent. 

Refer to following snippet:

The responseCode is either "phone", "google.com", "facebook.com", or "twitter.com".

```
    `import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
    import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
    .....
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
    data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
 
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
 
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
                String providerCode = response.getProviderType();
                ... 
            }  
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most recent solution is:

As noted [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/README.md#example-with-all-parameters-used)

```
var uiConfig = {
        callbacks: {
          signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
            var providerId = authResult.additionalUserInfo.providerId;
            //...
          },
          //..
       }
```

and for display in page

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        user.getIdToken().then(function (idToken) {

          $('#user').text(welcomeName + "(" + localStorage.getItem("firebaseProviderId")+ ")");
          $('#logged-in').show();
        }
    }
});
```