# Getting 'E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash android.os.TransactionTooLargeException' on clicking a Positive button of AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, firebase, facebook-android-sdk

I'm getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
```

and this too:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
```

while running below given code:

```
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    if (user != null) {
                        // User is signed in

                        if (isFacebookLoggedIn()) {

                            if (dialog == null) {

                                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);

                                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                View alertDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_unique_name_dialog, null);
                                uniqueUserName = (EditText) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.uniqueUserName);
                                usernameChoosen = (TextView) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.usernameChoosen);
                                usernameWarning = (TextView) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.usernameWarning);

                                usernameChoosen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                usernameWarning.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                builder.setTitle("Choose a unique username");
                                builder.setView(alertDialogView);
                                builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                    }
                                });
                                dialog = builder.create();
                            }
                            dialog.show();
                            dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    wantToCloseDialog = false;
                                    //Do stuff, possibly set wantToCloseDialog to true then...
                                    if (uniqueUserName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please choose a unique username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        wantToCloseDialog = false;
                                    } else {

                                        mDatabase.child("unique-usernames").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                                                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().contains(uniqueUserName.getText().toString())) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), uniqueUserName.getText().toString() + " is already taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        usernameChoosen.setText(uniqueUserName.getText().toString());
                                                        wantToCloseDialog = false;
                                                    } else {

                                                        // error is happening on execution of this code

                                                        Log.d("signedIn", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                                                        mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("name").setValue(user.getDisplayName());
                                                        mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("imageUID").setValue(user.getPhotoUrl());
                                                        mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("uniqueUserName").setValue(uniqueUserName.getText().toString());
                                                        mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("followers").setValue("00");
                                                        mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("following").setValue("00");
                                                        mDatabase.child("unique-usernames").child(ts).setValue(uniqueUserName.getText().toString());
                                                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
                                                        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                                                        progressDialog.setMessage("Signing up...");
                                                        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                                                        progressDialog.show();
                                                        wantToCloseDialog = true;
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    Log.d("signedIn", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                                                    mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("name").setValue(user.getDisplayName());
                                                    mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("imageUID").setValue(user.getPhotoUrl());
                                                    mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("uniqueUserName").setValue(uniqueUserName.getText().toString());
                                                    mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("followers").setValue("00");
                                                    mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("following").setValue("00");
                                                    mDatabase.child("unique-usernames").child(ts).setValue(uniqueUserName.getText().toString());
                                                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
                                                    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                                                    progressDialog.setMessage("Signing up...");
                                                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                                                    progressDialog.show();
                                                    wantToCloseDialog = true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                                        .make(coordinatorLayout, databaseError.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                                snackbar.show();
                                                wantToCloseDialog = false;
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    if(wantToCloseDialog)
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    //else dialog stays open. Make sure you have an obvious way to close the dialog especially if you set cancellable to false.
                                }
                            });
                        } else {

                            Log.d("signedIn", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                            mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("name").setValue(userName.getText().toString());
                            mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("uniqueUserName").setValue(uniqueUserName.getText().toString());
                            mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("followers").setValue("00");
                            mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("following").setValue("00");
                            mDatabase.child("unique-usernames").child(ts).setValue(uniqueUserName.getText().toString());
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
                            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    } else {
                        // User is signed out
                        Log.d("signedOut", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    }
                    // ...
                }
            };
```

I have never seen any such error before and that's why I have no idea what's happening here.

Please let me know what is causing this error!

Comment: You have two OnClick Listeners for your positive button on your dialog. This is probably what is causing the error.

Comment: removing one of them didn't helped. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking deeply into code at least 10-12 times, I got the problem here.

The solution was to add `.toString()` with `user.getPhotoUrl()` in this line of code: `mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("imageUID").setValue(user.getPhotoUrl());`

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38128667/6144372) gave me a bit hint. Thanks [qbix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4815718/qbix).

So, it has been solved now!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a listener for node `mDatabase.child("unique-usernames")`.  Then in the `onDataChange()` callback for that listener, you are modifying a child of that same node:

```
mDatabase.child("unique-usernames").child(ts).setValue(uniqueUserName.getText().toString());
```

This causes the listener callback to fire again, resulting in an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks, but this answer of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38128667/6144372 helped me a bit.