# How to determine if a Firebase user is signed in using email and password authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase authentication. The user can log in via e-mail password, google and facebook. How do I know if a user is logged in using an email-password? I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619628/how-to-determine-if-a-firebase-user-is-signed-in-using-facebook-authentication?answertab=active#tab-top)

and i tried this:

```
for (UserInfo user: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {
    if (!(user.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com") || user.getProviderId().equals("google.com"))) {
        System.out.println("User is signed in with Email");
    }
}
```

But when I use both google and email passwords if statement being true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [provider ID for email+password is `password`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/EmailAuthProvider.html#PROVIDER_ID). So:

```
for (UserInfo user: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {
    if (user.getProviderId().equals("password")) {
        System.out.println("User is signed in with email/password");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is what works for me:

> **user.getProvider()** returns **firebase**
>
> **user.getProviderData()** returns some Id.
>
> The list returned by **user.getProviders()** returns the login account type

Here's what I did:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < currentUser.getProviders().size(); i++) {
            if (!currentUser.getProviders().get(i).equals("google.com") && !currentUser.getProviders().get(i).equals("facebook.com")) {
               //User signed in with a custom account
               //Todo: call server DB or perform some task

            } else
               updateUI(currentUser);
        }

       // Todo: Complete login activity and switch to the main activity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if user email is empty or not , if it is empty means user has logged in without email

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())){
 phone = user.getPhoneNumber();
}
```