# How to know user is login by facebook or phone number in firebase ios (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to know **user is logged in by facebook account or phone number?** I am using firebase authentication for facebook and phone number login. Now I need to delete account from setting screen "**Delete Account**" Option.

As per the **firebase official documentation**, If we want to delete the user from auth we need to `reauthenticate` user first.

In my app I am providing the login by using both facebook and phone number so now I am getting confused how to differenciate the user is login by facebook or phone number. Once I get it (user login by facebook or phone number) I will go for the reauthentication and then delete the user by delete method calling of firebase auth.

Comment: Since a user can be signed in with multiple providers, you'll need to loop over the provider datas. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619628/how-to-determine-if-a-firebase-user-is-signed-in-using-facebook-authentication

Comment: The iOS version of Frank's answer is `for provider in (Auth.auth().currentUser?.providerData)! { print(provider.providerID) }`