# how to know if the users signed in or up using google or facebook sign button android firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using firebase in my android firebase app. I am using with it google sign and facebook sign. My problem is that google's and facebook sign buttons used to make sign up and sign in in the same time which means that the same button does sign in to the app and also sign up if the user isn't signed in the app. I need a way to know if the users signed up or in or up for both the facebook button and google button

Note: I don't want to know if the user is signed in using google or facebook but what I need is to know if the user has signed in in the app and he has an account before or it is the first time to sign in the app

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use this with `getProviderId()`:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) { 
                   // User is signed in
        try {
            for (UserInfo user : firebaseUser.getProviderData()) {
                if (user.getProviderId().equals("google.com")) {

                    System.out.println("User is signed in with Google");


                } else {

                    System.out.println("User is not signed in with Google");

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The same for Facebook:

```
if (user.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com"))
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38619970/4409113

Comment: this is not what I need. I need to know if the user has signed in or signed up not if he has signed with facebook or google

Comment: Updated the answer.