# How to check if user is logged in using password method in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to add password change functionality which is only visible to users logged with email/password.
I am also getting my user from the `onAuthChanged` method called in `useEffect` which runs on the app initialize.

I implemented code based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619628/how-to-determine-if-a-firebase-user-is-signed-in-using-facebook-authentication)

here is what I've tried:-

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user){
        for (UserInfo userinf: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {
          if (userinf.getProviderId().equals("password")) {
              System.out.println("User is signed in with email/password");
          }
      }
},[]);
```

But there is no Object named FirebaseAuth in 'firebase' library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add Java code to your JavaScript project, which won't work.

You'll have to convert the Java code you found to JavaScript, which shouldn't be too hard if you keep the reference documentation for both handy: [JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#providerdata), [Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getProviderData()).

I actually just noticed that the Firebase documentation also have guides on how to do this for [Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information) and [JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information). The latter contains this handy code snippet:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {
  user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
    console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
    console.log("  Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
    console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
    console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
    console.log("  Photo URL: " + profile.photoURL);
  });
}
```